# SVN - The pristine text with checksum '$sha1$5aa2d91900d7c70f2153f5f907946c7a339' was found in the DB but not on disk

Tags: svn, svnkit

During SVN update, I'm getting following error -

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155032: The pristine text with checksum 
'$sha1$5aa2d91900d7c70f2153f5f907946c7a339f' was found in the DB but not on disk
```

I googled but did not get how to resolve this. Can someone please help to understand how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells that there is a problem with the working copy Jenkins tries to update via SVNKit. Backup this working copy (just playing it safe) and replace it with a freshly checked out one. The error should not occur, but I would recommend that you monitor that for some time. Note that this problem could be a bug in SVNKit that you use in Jenkins for SVN support.